# Проверить поле по regex когда оно не пустое

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста с построением regex, по такому условию:
 если строка имет хоть один символ отличный от пробела(то есть не пустая) то надо проверить введено ли в ней слова flat или room. 
Если было введено room, flat, или пустая строка, или пробел, то вернуть true в противном случае false. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: А зачем вы предварительно проверяете что строка не пустая, а потом в условии у вас звучит что строка может быть пустой. И опять же "или пробел" имеется ввиду один пробел или их может быть много?

Comment: @pnp2000 просто все зависит от ошибок. Если в строке что-то есть то надо высветить одно сообщение. Но если в ней пробел или она пустая высветить другое сообщение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
string.matches("| +|room|flat"); // + стоит, если пробелов больше одного
```

---

Исходя из вашего комментария, возможно вам нужно это:

Проверка, пустая ли строка:

```java
string.isEmpty();
```

Проверка на пробел:

```java
string.equals(" ");
```

Если пробелов больше одного:

```java
string.matches(" +");
```

Comment: Я обычно проверяю на пустоту строки вот так string.length != 0

Comment: Можно и так. Можно и через `equals()`.

Comment: Просто такой метод обычно менее ресурсоёмкий

Comment: Не подойдет, если пробелов больше одного то тесты валятся.

Comment: Так в ТЗ ничего не говорится про то что пробелов может быть несколько

Comment: @pnp2000 alex safsafsd 10 минут назад оставил комментарий.

Comment: Для проверки на пустоту в классе `String` есть специальный метод - [isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--), а символ пробела в паттерне лучше указывать так - `\\s`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это не только символ пробела, это любой whitespace character.